# Making multiple trips using OR-Tools

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools

I am new to OR-Tools and I’m trying to make multiple trips for CVRP. After I have searched many examples, I still don’t get how time windows work. I have 129 stores, 200 vehicles. My aim is to decrease total costs(distance costs, vehicle hiring costs and fuel costs) by making more efficient routes with less vehicles. Every vehicle has their own capacity to carry products.

My constraints are:

- Working hours(13 hours for a vehicle in total)
- Vehicle capacity (Some vehicles have 10 pallets capacity, others have 18 pallets)
- The fuel cost of vehicles with 10 pallets and 18 pallets are different(for 10 pallets: 0.23, for 18 pallets:0.3)
- Waiting time (different at every store)
- I have start and end time for a shift but I don’t have certain time periods for stores like this vehicle has to be there at that time at that store)
  I give same values for time windows for every store because I don’t have a certain time periods. My model can’t use the time windows with this way, which values I need to give to time windows?

Here is my codes with dummy data;

```
def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem for 130 nodes."""
    data = {}
    data['distance_matrix'] = [[0.0,41.6523,42.2404,16.53,13.9472,12.1087],
[41.628,0.0,1.4118,25.6223,28.5948,33.7074],
[44.6087,3.1841,0.0,28.6023,31.5747,36.6873],
[16.79190,25.9814,26.5694,0.0,3.7579,8.8705],
[14.395,29.004,29.592,3.8829,0.0,5.2273],
[13.0226,32.936,33.5241,7.815,5.231,0.0]
    data['demands'] = [0.0, 6.0,7.0,6.0,4.0,5.0]
    data['vehicle_capacities'] = [10,18,18,10,18,18,10,18,18]
    data['num_vehicles'] = 9
    data['depot'] = 0
    data['vehicle_fuel_costs'] = [0.23,0.3,0.3,0.23,0.3,0.3,0.23,0.3,0.3]
    data['time_matrix'] = 
[[0.0,35.6016,36.865,17.8066,15.8583,16.1166],
[35.015,0.0,2.04,18.675,20.715,25.2933],
[37.9716,3.41833,0.0,21.6316,23.6716,28.25],
[17.8650,19.5466,20.81,0.0,3.565,8.1433],
[16.1483,21.41,22.6733,3.615,0.0,6.165],
[15.4233,24.505,25.7683,6.71,4.7616,0.0]]
    data['time_windows'] = 
[(0, 780),
 (0, 780),
 (0, 780),
 (0, 780),
 (0, 780),
 (0, 780)]
    data['service_time'] = [0.0,12.0,14.0,12.0,8.0,10.0]
    return data

def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    dist_dict = {}
    print(f'Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}')
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')
    total_time = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
            plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2}) -> '.format(
                manager.IndexToNode(index), solution.Min(time_var),
                solution.Max(time_var))
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2})\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index),
                                                    solution.Min(time_var),
                                                    solution.Max(time_var))
        plan_output += 'Time of the route: {}min\n'.format(
            solution.Min(time_var))
        print(plan_output)
        total_time += solution.Min(time_var)
    print('Total time of all routes: {}min'.format(total_time))
    return dist_dict, data

def main():
    """Solve the CVRP problem."""
    data = create_data_model()
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)
    callback_indices = []
    for vehicle_idx in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        def vehicle_callback(from_index, to_index, i=vehicle_idx):
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
            return data['vehicle_fuel_costs'][i] * data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]
        callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(vehicle_callback)
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(callback_index, vehicle_idx)
        callback_indices.append(callback_index)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleTransits(
        callback_indices,
        0,
        100000000000,
        True,
        'Distance')
    def demand_callback(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data['demands'][from_node]
    demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
        demand_callback)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data['vehicle_capacities'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity')
    callback_indices2 = []
    for vehicle_idx in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        def time_callback(from_index, to_index, i=vehicle_idx):
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
            return int(data['service_time'][to_node]) + data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]
        callback_index2 = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfVehicle(callback_index2, vehicle_idx)
        callback_indices2.append(callback_index2)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleTransits(
        callback_indices2,
        780,
        780,
        False,
    'Time')
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 60
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    if solution:
        dist_dict, data = print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)
        return dist_dict, data
    else:
        print('No solution with these constraints.')
        return None, None
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dist_dict, data = main()
    dist_dict, data
```

When I added time windows constraint, I couldn’t get a solution that’s why I didn’t give time windows and I added service time manually. I saw I need to duplicate depots to make multiple trips. I don’t get exactly how to make multiple trips but I guess it’s related to time windows. But my time windows values are same since I don’t have certain time periods.

So my first question is;

1)Is it possible to make multiple trips without time windows? If I need time windows, how should I arrange time windows values?

2)I want to decrease number of vehicles by making multiple trips. But vehicles shouldn’t visit same locations again and again in a day. One visit is enough for every store. For instance, one of the vehicles can make three trips and another one can make four trips with regard to total route time in a day. How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.